# Use Bundle to send a 2D string Array

Tags: android, runtime-error, bundle, multidimensional-array

I want to send a 2D array using bundle I used:

```
//TO SEND
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("value",string_array);

//TO GET
String[][] array_string = (String[][]) b.getSerializable("value");
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
02-19 08:22:58.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 08:22:58.582: E/AndroidRuntime(2412): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
activity ComponentInfo{com.example.statlite/com.example.statlite.GraphActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[][]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In Activity A


String[] arrayName;
Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("IntentName",arrayName);

In Activity B

String receivingArrayName[]=bundle.getStringArray("IntentName");
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to send a 2d array not a 1d array